# Haskell type annotation in function

Tags: haskell

Haskell doesn't seem to recognize my type annotation below. Why is this?

Here Runner is a wrapper for a function, with a default starting value for c (a "continuant"). In rmap, I want c to have a default "starting" value (for example, if c were [a] I would let that value be []). What's of course inconvenient here (and perhaps this is bad practice, feel free to suggest a better way) is that a type annotation is required since the domain of rmap does not involve the type c. However, why can I not fix this by a type annotation?

```
data ExitCode = Fail | OK | Success deriving (Eq, Show)

data Runner a b c = Runner {cont ::c
              , fun :: (a, c , ExitCode) ->(b,  c, ExitCode)}

class Pointed a where
  point :: a

rmap:: (Pointed c) => (a->b) -> Runner a b c
rmap f = Runner (point::c) (\(x,y,z) -> (f x,y,z))
```

The error is the following. (It seems to be interpreting c as c1.)

```
Could not deduce (Pointed c1) arising from a use of `point'
from the context (Pointed c)
  bound by the type signature for
             rmap :: Pointed c => (a -> b) -> Runner a b c
  at Runner.hs:39:8-44
Possible fix:
  add (Pointed c1) to the context of
    an expression type signature: c1
    or the type signature for
         rmap :: Pointed c => (a -> b) -> Runner a b c
In the first argument of `Runner', namely `(point :: c)'
In the expression: Runner (point :: c) (\ (x, y, z) -> (f x, y, z))
In an equation for `rmap':
    rmap f = Runner (point :: c) (\ (x, y, z) -> (f x, y, z))
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to use type variables in a definition like that, you need the `ScopedTypeVariables` language extension, but in this case you don't need the scoped type variable at all, just use

```
rmap :: Pointed c => (a -> b) -> Runner a b c
rmap f = Runner point (\(x, y, z) -> (f x, y, z))
```

If you really really want to have `(point :: c)`, you can do

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

-- other declarations

rmap :: forall a b c. Pointed c => (a -> b) -> Runner a b c
rmap f = Runner (point :: c) (\(x, y, z) -> (f x, y, z))
```

With `ScopedTypeVariables` you also have to explicitly use the `forall` syntax and have `a` and `b` declared as well.  Again, it isn't necessary for this particular problem, GHC can automatically figure out which instance of `Pointed` to use.

Even with GHC 7.8, the type signature isn't even required, it can derive it automatically:

```
> let rmap f = Runner point (\(x, y, z) -> (f x, y, z))
> :t rmap
rmap :: Pointed c => (a -> b) -> Runner a b c
```

---

The origin of this error is that when you had `(point :: c)` without `ScopedTypeVariables`, the `c` in the function definition is a different `c` in the type signature.  This works with concrete types like `Int` because they're already in scope, but not so with type variables.

---

So as to why this works without having `c` in the domain of the function: GHC's type inference is really smart.  It'll let you pass around a generic value until the point that you require it to be concrete, then all the right instances get used.  For example, if I instead had something like

```
> data Test a b c = Test { t :: c, x :: (a, b) } deriving (Eq, Show)
> instance Pointed [Double] where point = [1, 2, 3]    -- Requires FlexibleInstances
> let test :: Pointed c => a -> b -> Test a b c
|     test a b = Test point (a, b)
> test 1 "test" :: Test Int String [Double]
Test {t = [1.0,2.0,3.0], x = (1,"test")}
```

Even though `c` doesn't appear as an argument, it's still possible for the type checker to figure out which instance to use when I've specified that the return type is `Test Int String [Double]`.  Without specifying the signature, it instead gives me the error

```
<interactive>:30:1:
    No instance for (Pointed c0) arising from a use of `it'
    The type variable `c0' is ambiguous
    Note: there is a potential instance available:
      instance Pointed [Double] -- Defined at <interactive>:19:10
    In the first argument of `print', namely `it'
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

because it doesn't know what instance of `Pointed` to use.